# Como importar dados do banco para campo do formulário

Tags: php, mysql, formulário

Tenho um sistema de gestão de cursos onde o usuário tem acesso a uma tabela com todas as turmas de todos os cursos e opta por se inscrever em um.

Quando o usuário for se inscrever, vai abrir um formulário com os campos que ele deve preencher e o campo com o nome da formação e turma, porém, esses campos eu quero que já estejam preenchidos conforme a formação e turma da linha da tabela que ele clicou.

**A tabela de consulta:**

```
<h1 style="
text-align: center;
height: 7;
margin-top: 150;
margin-bottom: 70
margin-top:130;
"> Consulta de turmas </h1>
<form method="post" action="selectT.php">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="NOME">Nome: </label>
      <input class="form-control" id="NOME" placeholder="Nome da turma" name="NOME">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="DATA">Data</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="DATA" placeholder="Data da formação" name="DATA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="LOCAL">Local: </label>
      <select class="form-control" id="LOCAL" name="LOCAL">
        <option>PR</option>
        <option>PL</option>
        <option>SP</option>
        <option>RJ</option>  
        <option>FR</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 22;">Buscar</button>
</form>

<?php
//Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db_formacao') or die(mysql_error());
$qry = mysql_query("select * from turmas");

//Pegando os nomes dos campos
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
  $fields[] = mysql_field_name($qry,$i);
}

//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse" style="margin-top:50;background-color: #37444a; color:lightgrey;"> <tr>';

for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
  $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
}

//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
  background-color: #86979e;
  color: #37444a;    
">';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
  $table .= '<tr>';
  for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
  }

  // Adicionando botão de exclusão
  $table .= '<td><form action="inscricao.php" method="post">'; //formulário com método post que vai para deleteF.php
  $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
  $table .= '<button class="btn btn-primary">Inscreva-se</button>'; //aqui está o seu botão
  $table .= '</form></td>';
}

//Finalizando a tabela
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

//Imprimindo a tabela
echo $table;

?>
```

**O formulário para inscrição:**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db_formacao";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT NOME FROM turmas";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
}
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1 style="
                margin-top:100px;">Inscrição</h1>
            <p> </p>
            <p class="lead"></p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <form id="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateP.php" style="
                    text-align: left;
                    margin-top:50px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="FORMACAO">Formação: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="FORMACAO" name="FORMACAO" value="<?=$row['nome']?>">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="TURMA">Turma: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="TURMA" name="TURMA">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="COLABORADOR">Colaborador: </label>
                            <select  class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR">
                                <?php

                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="PREVISTO">Status: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="PREVISTO" name="PREVISTO" value="Previsto">
                         </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline disabled">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="STATUS" id="STATUS" value="Realizado" disabled> Realizado
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**A consulta:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O formulário:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: porque que quase todas as pessoas ainda usam `mysql_*`? devias refazer para PDO ou MySQLi ou se não teu site ta exposto a vários tipos de ataques...

Comment: Eu uso uma versão antiga do php e não posso mudar porque tem muitos sistemas rodando nessa versão.

Comment: qual é a versão do php ?

Comment: A versão é php 5.2.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Na tabela de consulta, neste trecho**

```
.......................
.......................
//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
  background-color: #86979e;
  color: #37444a;    
">';

$table .= '<form action="inscricao.php" method="post">'; //formulário com método post que vai para deleteF.php

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){

  $table .= '<tr>';

  for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
  }

  // Adicionando botão de exclusão
      $table .= '<td><input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
      //$table .= "<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ID\" value=\"".$r["ID"]."\">";
      $table .= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Inscreva-se</button> </td>'; //aqui está o seu botão

  $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</form>';

//Finalizando a tabela
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

//Imprimindo a tabela
echo $table;
```

**as alterações foram:**

1. estruturação do formulário, linhas (tr e td) da tabela
2. especificar o type do button  `<button type="submit"`

> Sobre o atributo type dos buttons

1. submit: O botão envia os dados do formulário para o servidor.
2. button: O botão não possui comportamento padrão. Ele pode ter scripts do lado do cliente associado com os eventos do elemento, no qual são acionados quando o evento ocorrer.

[`<button>` - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

**E no formulário para inscrição:**

```
 ................
 $id=$_POST["ID"];
 $sql = "SELECT ID,NOME FROM turmas where ID='$id'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 ................
 ................
 <label  for="TURMA">Turma: </label>
 <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="TURMA" name="TURMA" value="<?=$row['ID'] ?>">
```

Answer (score 3):

Para você definir um valor inicial a campos de formulário, você segue esses padrões:

### Para inputs tipo text, email, password, etc.

Define o valor pelo atributo `value`. Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" value="João da Silva">
```

### Para inputs tipo checkbox e radio:

Define o atributo `checked` para o que precisa estar marcado. Exemplo:

```
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Masculino" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Feminino">
```

### Para textarea:

Basta colocar o conteúdo dentro da tag. Exemplo:

```
<textarea name="mensagem">Lorem ipsun sit dolor omet</textarea>
```

### Para select:

Define o atributo `selected` para o option que deve já vir selecionado, exemplo:

```
<select name="cidade">
    <option value="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="São Paulo" selected="selected">São Paulo</option>
    <option value="Curitiba">Curitiba</option>
</select>
```

### Segue um exemplo de formulário agora:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
.radio-group {
  display: block;
}
.radio-group label {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" value="João da Silva">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Sexo:</label>
    <span class="radio-group">
      <input type="radio" id="masculino" name="sexo" value="Masculino" checked="checked">
      <label for="masculino">Masculino</label>
      <input type="radio" id="feminino" name="sexo" value="Feminino">
      <label for="feminino">Feminino</label>
    </span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="mensagem">Mensagem:</label>
    <textarea id="mensagem" name="mensagem">Lorem ipsun sit dolor omet</textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="cidade">Cidade:</label>
    <select id="cidade" name="cidade">
        <option value="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</option>
        <option value="São Paulo" selected="selected">São Paulo</option>
        <option value="Curitiba">Curitiba</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </p>
</form>
```

### Exemplo trazendo os valores do MySQL pelo PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT nome, sexo, mensagem, cidade FROM pessoas WHERE id_pessoa = 10;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    ?>
        <form>
            <p>
                <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
                <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" value="<?=$row['nome']?>">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Sexo:</label>
                <span class="radio-group">
                    <input type="radio" id="masculino" name="sexo" value="Masculino"<?php if($row['sexo'] == 'Masculino') { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?>>
                    <label for="masculino">Masculino</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="feminino" name="sexo" value="Feminino"<?php if($row['sexo'] == 'Feminino') { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?>>
                    <label for="feminino">Feminino</label>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="mensagem">Mensagem:</label>
                <textarea id="mensagem" name="mensagem"><?=$row['nome']?></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="cidade">Cidade:</label>
                <select id="cidade" name="cidade">
                    <option value="Rio de Janeiro"<?php if($row['cidade'] == 'Rio de Janeiro') { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?>>Rio de Janeiro</option>
                    <option value="São Paulo"<?php if($row['cidade'] == 'São Paulo') { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?>>São Paulo</option>
                    <option value="Curitiba"<?php if($row['cidade'] == 'Curitiba') { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?>>Curitiba</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
            </p>
        </form>
    <?php
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Sua resposta foi muito útil, porém, eu quero que o que esteja nesse value seja retirado do banco de dados.

Comment: Tentei colocar value="<?php echo $nome['NOME']?>" mas eu devo ter que especificar a tabela e fazer a conexão com banco, certo?

Comment: exato, neste caso precisa primeiro conectar com o banco, recuperar os valores e depois imprimir no value exatamente como você colocou

Comment: acrescentei um exemplo com dados trazidos do MySQL pelo PHP

Comment: Então, copiei seu código e adaptei pro meu, mas sem o else porque não tava funcionando; Ainda não funciona. Vou editar minha pergunta, se der, tem como me mostrar onde eu to errando?

Comment: Ajudamos no que puder

Comment: Aaaah, obrigada! Você é bem cuidadoso com as respostas, devia ser professor.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64430/discussion-between-diego-marques-and-mariana-ferreira).